# how can i implement intertitial ads in recipe app

Tags: android, admob, ads

i make an app of recipe and i want to add intertitial ads in my app ,i have two question :
my app contain an listview each click of an item gives you another activity showing information about this type of food 
my first question can i show intertitial in every activity of this app i mean when user open my app and looking for first dish give him an intertitial after few second if he changes of another dish give him another intertitial for every item of listview can i do that ,
if i can what is the best implementation of this ads in my app , if not what can i do and thank you very much

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

Answer (score 0):

Check out the official google doc for Interstitial Ads

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#adding_interstitial_ads_to_an_activity

Answer (score 0):

for reference please check this [Android How to Integrate Google AdMob in your App](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the references the other two have provided.

But I also strongly suggest you don't use separate Activities for each recipe. Instead use a single Activity that holds long lived artefacts like your InterstitialAd and use Fragments to show each recipe. It will make it much easier to manage your app's lifecycle.